# Python: Marble Sorting game: works for some numbers -- infinite loop for others

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a marble sorting game in Python. Have it working for some cases, but it fails for others (esp longer number tuples). In general, I am using a basic method to determine whether to switch or rotate (based on just a comparison of first two numbers). It just injects some randomness to the selection -- not perfect but should work?

My goal is to two fold

1. What am I doing wrong? Have the two classes been structured right?
2. Once I get the code working (regardless of time optimization), I would like to explore alternate ways / better ways to select rotate or switch.

The Board class

```
class MarblesBoard:
    """creates a marble board with number marbles in specific spots"""
    def __init__(self, marble_sequence):
        self.board = [x for x in marble_sequence]

    def switch(self):
        """switch the marbles in position 0 and 1"""
        self.board[0], self.board[1] = self.board[1], self.board[0]
        return self.board

    def rotate(self):
         """
         Rotates item in position o to position N-1. All remaning items are moved as a result (1 step to the left)
         """
        self.board = self.board[1:] + [self.board[0]]
        return self.board
    
    def is_sorted(self):
        return self.board == sorted(self.board)
    
    def should_rotate(self):
        # condition can be used to determine whether to start with rotate of switch
        return self.board[0] > self.board[1]
```

The Solver class

```
class Solver:
    """solves the marble sorting game when given a marble board as input"""

    def __init__(self, marbles_board):
        self.marbles_board = marbles_board

    def solve(self):
        steps = 0

        while not self.marbles_board.is_sorted():
            if steps == 10:break
            if self.marbles_board.should_rotate():
                self.marbles_board.rotate()
            else:
                self.marbles_board.switch()
            
            steps += 1
        
        print(f"Number of steps: {steps}")
        print(self.marbles_board)
```

Test 1 - works

```
board1 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2))
solver1 = Solver(board1)
solver1.solve()
```

Test 2 - fails

```
board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2,4))
solver2 = Solver(board2)
solver2.solve()
```

Comment: Your "test 2" is passing `board1` again, not `board2`.  Perhaps it fails when given an already solved board.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected it so board2. There is something fundamentally wrong with the logic (The query failed with a step size of 10000000 (and I get the same answer 3,0,1,2,4

Answer (score 0):

You will kick yourself when you see it!!! Spoiler alert you are passing the already solved board1 from the first test into second test, so it is already sorted. So it returns Number of steps: 0

```
board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2,4))
solver2 = Solver(board1) #<<<<< Here
solver2.solve()
```

should look like this

```
board1 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2))
solver1 = Solver(board1)
solver1.solve()

board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2,4))
solver2 = Solver(board2)
solver2.solve()
```

To address your second concern. Switching like this is just fine. Alternatively you could keep switch states in a list and choose like that.

Something I would recommend you look at doing different in your solve method is not using break statements, and breaking your while loop with logic. For example a flag that becomes true when steps == 10. Break statements are equivalent to empty exceptions. It may fix the issue in the moment but will give no help when your code goes off the rails.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I revised my question with after correcting the typo. I am indeed getting an infinite loop. I may have figured it out and am changing the should_rotate function